# can't find DFS with other user in RDP session

Tags: windows, active-directory, rdp, dfs

I connect with RDP to Windows 10 with a user than not have privileges over te DFS. For this reason, Windows request other credentials. I put the credentials of a user with privileges but Windows don't find the shared folder. But if I put the credential in the RDP session is find fast.

eg:

Initial user with RDP: user1

User with privileges: admin

The user1 access to the device with RDP session. In Windows Explorer type \domain.local\public and need credentials. The user put the credentials of admin and windows can't find the folder.

But if admin access initially and put the same folder \domain.local\public can find the folder.

Test:

If I put the IP of the server Wors but I need that the user finds the path with DFS. eg: \domain.local\public not with \xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx\public

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use the correct user (admin) for the *first* logon on the ressource. When the Windows Explorer is used to browse a servers ressources, it will initiate the session with the logged on user (user1, which you do not want in this case).

You can use `net use` after the login to use different credentials for the ressource from the credentials you used to login into your Windows (RDP) Session.

```
net use \\server /USER:<domain>\<name>
```

The `/persistent` switch will save the credentials.

Note that this will not work, if the DFS or SMB ressource you are trying to access is placed on a domain controler, as DCs do provide just one session (including logon).

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, as I now understand: DFS Client works at a low level because it resolves DFS links to real SMB shares as DNS.